# I'd like to manipulate the way using gpu in tensorflow lite, what can i study for that

Tags: gpu, tensorflow-lite

At first, let me explain what i have to do.
My develop enviroment is Tizen OS. may be you are unfamilier that, anyway this os is using linux kernel based redhat and targeting on mobile, tv, etc.. And my target device is consists of exynos 5422 and arm mali-t628.
My main work is implement some gpu library to let tensorflow lite's operation can use the library.
I proceeded to build and install tensorflow lite as a rpm package file.
I am googling many times about the tensorflow and gpu. and get some useless information about cuda. i didnt see any info for my case(tizen and mali gpu).
i think linux have gpu instruction like the cpu or library.. but i cant find them.
can you suggest search keyword or document?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to nvidia’s cuda toolkit page, where you can find the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/) and 
[Training](https://developer.nvidia.com/accelerated-computing-training) buttons / options.

Also there’s the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) wich i myself find very usefull and helpull for CUDA.

I believe that one or two of those may help you.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA is for NVidia GPU. Mali is not NVidia's, but ARM's. So you CANNOT use CUDA in your given hardware. Besides, if you want CUDA, you'd better drop Tensorflow-lite and use Tensorflow.

1. If you want to use CUDA, get a hardware with supported NVidia GPU (e.g., x64 machine with NVidia GPU). Note that you can use Tensorflow-GPU & CUDA/CUDNN in Tizen with x64+NVidia GPU. You just need to be careful on nvidia GPU kernel driver version and userspace driver version. Because NVidia's GPU userspace driver and CUDA/CUDNN are statically built, its Linux drivers are compatible with Tizen. (I've tested tensorflow-gpu, CUDA/CUDNN in Tizen with NVidia driver version 111... probably in winter, 2017)
2. If you want to use Tizen/Tensorflow-lite in the given hardware, forget CUDA.